# I'm getting a "Type Error: Cannot read property of undefined" in this line of code

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, faye

I'm trying to test a message I am sending from a client through faye.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"message":"Hi there."}' http://localhost:8000/message
```

This is the culript line.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;message&#39; of undefined<br>
```

UPDATE: The culript might actually be here...

```
app.post('/message', function(req, res) {
  bayeux.getClient().publish('/channel', {text: req.body.message});
  res.send(200);
});
```

Unfortunately, I get this error. For some reason, it sees message as an undefined property,and I'm not sure why.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you post the code of the /message end-point on your Node application? It looks as if there's an issue on that side. :)

Comment: Hi. I updated the original post. Thanks!

Comment: what does this  return: bayeux.getClient()?

Comment: A nice `console.log(req)` should hint at why `body` is `undefined` and where that message actually is

Comment: @akaphenom, it looks as if he's using Faye (http://faye.jcoglan.com/node/clients.html), but this shouldn't cause any issues, as there isn't any error stating that ``bayeux.getClient()`` is undefined or anything. :)

I think @JSelser is on the right track, with checking the output of ``req``.

Comment: @JSelser - Hmm. I've tried that but I don't seem to get anything that helps...? Actually, console.log is not even printing anything at all!

Comment: @MH1993, even in the Node server log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the required body-parsing middleware, such as [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)'s `.json()` middleware.

Install that module and add

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

somewhere before your routes.